# Using own, custom css in TYPO3

Tags: css, typo3

I'm testing the use of a static html template for TYPO3 (in typo3 directory). I copied the fragment `<body> ... </body>`

It should be like on img_1a:

[image: img_1a]

and it's like img_1b, instead:

[image: img_1b]

Sure, the original template "introduction" can not load my own style.css

I followed the instructions as here, img_2:

[How to include a custom CSS file in TYPO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137653/how-to-include-a-custom-css-file-in-typo3)

[image: img_2]

Answer (score 0):

There is CSS yet included from the Introduction Package. You should either remove this CSS or overwrite the CSS.

Comment: I have already copied the original template with a different name and hide the original. It looks like it works. It remains to remove the original css.

Comment: You need to look into the TypoScript Object Browser in the TYPO3 backend to get where CSS is included and how. You can find a documentation about debugging TypoScript here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/7.6/TypoScriptTemplates/Debugging/Index.html

Comment: You need to look for `includeCSSLibs` and `includeCSS` if there are files you don't want. These settings you can clear.

Comment: The original css has been removed but can not load custom css >> remax-prestige.pl/typo3

Comment: Please show us the snippet that you used to remove the original css, maybe the entire file it it is not to much.