# TYPO3: How to add a css and JS on the backend

Tags: javascript, php, css, typo3, element

How do i add  **css** and  **javascript** file(s) on the backend?

I would like to use those files for **custom created content elements** in order to make them more appealing for the user.

**System**: TYPO3 v9 
**Mode**: Composer Mode
**Target**: Custom Content element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a custom CSS file in TYPO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137653/how-to-include-a-custom-css-file-in-typo3)

Comment: @chris G not even close to duplicate. read the content again carefully

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In TYPO3 v9 you will have to do the following and on every mode

**CSS**

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['your_extension_key'] = array();
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['your_extension_key']['name'] = 'My Awesome Name';
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['your_extension_key']['stylesheetDirectories'] = array(
    'visual' => 'EXT:yourextension/Resources/Public/Css/Backend',
    'theme' => 'EXT:yourextension/Resources/Public/Css/Monokai'
);
```

The path here (CSS) is a directory, so it will read all the files in the pointed directory.

**JS**

```
$renderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
$renderer->addJsFile('yourextension/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Backend.js', 'text/javascript', false, false, '', true,  '|', false, '');
$renderer->addJsFile('yourextension/Resources/Public/JavaScript/another.js', 'text/javascript', false, false,  '', false, '|', false, '');
```

**Parameters:**

```
addJsFile(
       $file, 
       $type = 'text/javascript'
       $compress = true,
       $forceOnTop = false,
       $allWrap = '',
       $excludeFromConcatenation = false,
       $splitChar = '|',
       $async = false,
       $integrity = ''
);
```

In large files, it might have some problems with the loading, but if anyone could confirm that, i would really appreciate it.

**Additional information:**

If you want to use TYPO3's jQuery (**strongly recommended it in order to avoid conflicts**) you should use the following as well:

```
require(["jquery"], function($) {
   //your awesome function
});
```

You could use a condition as well to make sure that it is loaded on the backend:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
   $renderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
   ...
}
```