# Adding jQuery function in TYPO3 backend

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I need to a custom jQuery function in my TYPO3 backend when Im opening the "Page"-view.

I added a hook for the preProcess

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS'] 
['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem'] 
['tx_dashboard'] =
    \vendor\dashboard\Hooks\Backend\IconCorrection::class;
```

And in my IconCorrection I added

```
public function preProcess(PageLayoutView &$parentObject, &$drawItem, &$headerContent, &$itemContent, array &$row)
{
    GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PageRenderer::class)
        ->addRequireJsConfiguration([
            'paths' => [
                'iconCorrection'=>'/typo3conf/ext/dashboard/Resources/Public/JavaScript/hidePreviewIcon.js',
            ],
            'shim' => [
                'iconCorrection' => ['jquery'],
            ],
        ]);

}
}
```

In my hidePreviewIcon.js I have a console.log
I want something like `$(".btn").hide();` but for now just testing if the js is loaded.

In my dev-tools I see that the js was loaded, but the console.log wasnt executed.

What Im missing? 
And can I just using `addJsFile` instead of `addRequireJsConfiguration`
Im using TYPO3 v8.7.2

EDIT:

I added

```
$renderer =\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
$renderer->addJsFile('/typo3conf/ext/trumpf_editordashboard/Resources/Public/JavaScript/hidePreviewIcon.js', 'text/javascript', false, false, '', true, '|', false, '');
```

to my `preProcess()`function.

Now the .js was loaded and executed a console.log();
But my

```
$(document).ready(){$(".btn").hide();
```

doesnt work. I think its executed too early

EDIT 2: Did the trick:

```
$(function(){
$('#typo3-contentIframe').ready(function(){
    console.log("loaded");
    $(".btn").hide();

});
});
```

Comment: what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969780/typo3-how-to-add-a-css-and-js-on-the-backend

Comment: forgot to say that Im using v8.7.2

Comment: Can you share some of the executed code? If the JS was loaded, but not executed, this looks strange to me

Comment: @TedLogan it works with v8 as well :)

Comment: Ah alright. Now the .js is loaded and a `console.log("foo");` was executed.
But the `$(".btn").hide();` doesnt work. Maybe it was executed too early?

Comment: Should I post my comment as an answer? Did it help you?

Comment: Yeah, it was the solution